# Внешний ключ или достаточно триггера?

Tags: sql, база-данных, firebird

Возник вопрос касаемо SQL (сразу говорю, что я SQL знаю не совсем хорошо).
К примеру, в таблице `Касса` нужно обновлять данные, которые изменяют в `Товарах` или `Пациентах`.
Таблица CashBox и Cashless (одинаковые, только в одну наличная, в другую - безналичная оплата)

```
CREATE TABLE CashBox(ID INTEGER GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY PRIMARY 
KEY, Operation VARCHAR(1000), Income DOUBLE PRECISION, Consumption DOUBLE 
PRECISION, Balance DOUBLE PRECISION, DateTime TIMESTAMP);
```

Сделал внутреннюю таблицу для идентификаторов IntCashBox, IntCashless

```
CREATE TABLE IntCashBox (ID INTEGER GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY 
PRIMARY KEY, SourcePatientID INTEGER NOT NULL, SourceGoodsID INTEGER NOT 
NULL, CONSTRAINT fk_SourcePatientID(SourcePatientID) references 
Patients(id), CONSTRAINT fk_SourceGoodID references 
fk_SourceGoodID(SourceGoodsID));
```

Таблица (предыдущая версия) до `FOREIGN KEY`:

```
CREATE TABLE IntCashBox (ID INTEGER GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY PRIMARY 
KEY, SourceID INTEGER, TableName VARCHAR(50));
```

Вот я думаю, можно ли использовать `WHERE` в `FOREIGN KEY` (чтобы указать, из какой таблицы пришли данные) ?
Суть такова:  ID могут быть одинаковые в `Товарах` и `Пациентах`, а исключить дублирование надо просто сделав пометку, из какой таблицы пришли данные.

Делал триггер (это до `FOREIGN KEY`), в нем-то можно и без `FOREIGN KEY` делать все, т.е. триггер для таблиц есть и все работает корректно, т.е. пометка, какая таблица пишется в `TableName` и в триггере обновление проходит корректно (лишний код убрал):

```
 SELECT SourceID, TableName FROM IntCashBox WHERE SourceID = old.ID into 
     :intSourceID, :sourceTableName;
 --и определялось, где обновлять
 UPDATE CashBox
    SET Income = new.Amount, Balance = new.Amount - Consumption 
    WHERE :intSourceID = old.ID AND :sourceTableName = 'Patients';
```

И вот так определялось:

```
if (new.PaymentType = 'Наличная оплата') then
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO IntCashBox ...
    --и собственно определялась таблица и вставлялось/обновлялось
    --там были поля SourceID и TableName, по которым и определял
END
ELSE
BEGIN
      INSERT INTO Cashless
END
```

Можно было бы триггер оставить и не использовать `FOREIGN KEY`, но я вот думаю, при бэкапе и восстановлении базы идентификаторы сбрасываются или нет(если не просто копировать файл базы, да так и не делают)? К примеру, в крайнем случае, если вдруг придется пересоздавать базу(не значит, что придется, просто рассматриваю самые крайние случаи), чтобы ID были корректны, для этого вроде и нужны внешние ключи?

**Суть вопроса** - можно решать такие вопросы исключительно триггером, или все равно желательно `FOREIGN KEY`? Вообще в таких случаях внешний ключ обязателен или нет?

Comment: Если у вас идет ссылка на две таблицы - одним `Foreign Key` тут не обойтись. Надо делать ссылку на обе таблицы, и тогда записывать только нужную. Но вполне можно сделать триггер( хотя ИМХО, лучше такие вещи делать на уровне кода, а не на уровне БД)

Comment: Спасибо за помощь. Значит оставлю триггер, т.к. на уровне кода у меня немного другие вещи идут.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Таблица CashBox и Cashless (одинаковые, только в одну наличная, в другую - безналичная оплата)

В этом корень всех проблем. Таблица должна быть одна, а в ней - дополнительное поле `IS_CASH`, где 1 будет означать "наличные", а 0 - "безналичная оплата". После этого все резко упростится.